# How to write functionality for back arrow which appears when search is opened in action bar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i have a collapseActionView search in actionbar..A back arrow appears in the place of home button in actionbar when we press on search button...on focusing edittext soft keyboard appears...i have a problem when we click on the back arrow without submitting the search value the soft keyboard doesnot hide itself...how to write functionality for the backarrow which appears in the actionbar when the search view is open?

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar_l, menu);
        } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        } else {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        }
        View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.my_action).getActionView();




        /** Get the edit text from the action view */
        txtSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.myActionEditText);

        /** Setting an action listener */

        ImageView Search = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.search);
        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                search_value = txtSearch.getText().toString();
                if (txtSearch.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please enter search values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            Display.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Action_search", txtSearch.getText()
                            .toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    txtSearch.setText("");
                }
            }

        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

i wrote functionality for home button but it doesnot work

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle action bar actions click
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
//      
//       
//       
    case android.R.id.home:  

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         // count the active fragment
//       if(getSupportFragmentManager().getStackBackEntryCount() > 0) {
//           // hide soft method as above
//           InputMethodManager mImm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
//           mImm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
//           // do the pop backstack
//           getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); 
//       } else {  
//           // some stuff like finish the activity
         }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write this code in onPause:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
}
```

Comment: where should i declare onPause function